# Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception'

Tags: zend-framework

I am getting the following error on zend framework:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)' in F:\wamp\www\helloworld\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:245 
Stack trace: 
#0 F:\wamp\www\helloworld\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(946):Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))  
#1 F:\wamp\www\helloworld\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(212): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()  
#2 F:\wamp\www\helloworld\web_root\index.php(10): Zend_Controller_Front::run('../application/...')  
#3 {main} thrown in F:\wamp\www\helloworld\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php on line 245
```

What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 10):

In index.php file write

`$frontController->setParam('useDefaultControllerAlways', true);`
`$frontController->dispatch();`

Alternatively you can write following line in [production] section of application.ini file:

`resources.frontController.params.useDefaultControllerAlways = 1`

Comment: Thanks, that helped me find a similar issue.  I had an existing application and I decided to see what would happen if I reorganized the default controllers and moved them into the modules folder.  I made a Git branch for the test, but the folders lived on after switching to another branch. Zend apparently checks for the modules version first in /application/modules/default. My application was crashing because of the empty modules/default folder.

Answer (score 6):

You have probably (re)moved/edited the ErrorController.php file, which can be found in

```
/application/controllers/
```

An other possibility is that you have configured your application to look after an not-existing Error controller.

Answer (score 2):

I got a same error ,and then i find out the reason,it's just a syntax error in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Zend is looking for the view script inside the **/application/views/scripts** directory. If you do not want to use automatic rendering, then in the controller class use:

```
public function init()
{
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
}
```

This will stop automatic rendering and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Zend is looking for the Controller in the normal controllers dir.
So Set this config

```
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "Default"
```

and create your Default_ErrorController class in the Default Module dir.

it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is not your errorController.php file. Main problem is error in your code if code will be free from error, your code will not ask about errorController.php

In your controller file action just put `die("stop execution");`  from top to bottom after each statement

you will find out a statement, who is responsible for this error. just rectify this error