# how should my .htaccess file look like so it ignores js files?

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess

I didn't know there was something funny with it until I tried to inject a js file into a view with this:

```
$this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl('/js/planilla.js'));
echo $this->headScript();
```

Now, I'm using the Zend Framework and there's no problem when I do the same thing with any css file within the /public/css folder so I really don't nknow what the problem might be. The js folder and js file DO EXIST, and when I try to just access it (http://domain.local/js/planilla.js) through the browser I get the following error message:

> Exception information:
>
> Message: Invalid controller specified (js)
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /home/fiodorovich/library/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
>
> ## 1 /home/fiodorovich/library/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
>
> ## 2 /home/fiodorovich/library/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
>
> ## 3 /home/fiodorovich/public_html/gisele/public/index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
>
> ## 4 {main}
>
> Request Parameters:
>
> array (
>     'controller' => 'js',
>     'action' => 'planilla.js',
>     'module' => 'default',
>   )

Right now my .htaccess looks like this:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^.*/gisele.local/.*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Any help whatsoever will be welcomed and thud, thanks in advance...

EDIT: the vhost file

EDIT2: I got this thing to work.

I had to add this line to the application.ini file for it to work:

```
resources.frontController.params.useDefaultControllerAlways = 1
```

Comment: deleting a question once it has been answered is not the way Stack Overflow works. Rather, it will keep around questions that may be useful for visitors in the future. Your request to delete the question has been denied, though I have to note that you're still within your right to do so yourself, though I would also advice against it unless you see no gain for future visitors of SO from this question.

Comment: @lasse I don't have a problem with the question remaining here if it could be of anyone's interest. I sure spent a long time trying to figure out what wasn't working, however I found the answer to it in a different thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130530/uncaught-exception-zend-controller-dispatcher-exception . If you check you'll see that the second answer actually responds to what I had been looking for. However that question wasn't voted as the right one. You've been here for much longer and thus know whether someone might find this helpful or not. Thanks for letting me notice.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^.*/gisele.local/.*)$  [NC]
```

looks suspicious. Try to comment it.
My .htaccess file looks like this. And it is absolutably workable.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: if I comment it I get a 404 for every page but the index

Comment: Have you removed "[OR]" in the preceding line, then?

Comment: @akmond, it still doesn't work. I'm updating the question with a copy of my vhost

Comment: Do you really need MultiViews ?

Comment: I don't know. I deleted it and it's the same though

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess is fine. Try http://domain.local/js/ and check if your files are still there.

The zend framework is taking your js directory as a controller so, is "js" inside your public directory as css? you could also try this to make sure.

```
RewriteRule ^js(.*)$ – [NC,L]
```

or could be your enviroment settings. let me know what happens.

Comment: the folder is in there and if I go to http://domain.local/js/ I see the files. however when I add RewriteRule ^js(.*)$ – [NC,L] I get the 404 error

Comment: @la_f0ka well that means your htaccess is working fine. you should be able to navigate and open the file through http://domain.local/js